# How can we define the events method in util.js or exernal js file and export that method in lwc component

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, es6

How can we define the events method in util.js or external js file and pass event parameters, like handleOnclick(event)?

For Example, I have one lwc component named - helloWorld
and in my helloWorld.js I have the event click method

helloWorld.js

```
**clickedButtonLabel;
test1 = false;
handleClick(event) {
    this.clickedButtonLabel = event.target.label;
    test1=true
}**
```

but I want to write all logic related to this method in external js / util.js and import it here in helloWorld.js
Can someone help me to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For common methods that should be used in multiple places, you have three basic choices.

First, you can export the method, and then call it from your component.

```
let test1 = false
function handleClick(event) {
  this.clickedButtonLabel = event.target.label;
  test1 = true
}
export { handleClick }
```

Note that in this case, `this` is undefined by default, and `test1` will be shared by all components that use this method. In other words, test1 is effectively a static variable. You can fix `this` with `.bind`:

```
handleClick.bind(this)(event);
```

Note that the imported method won't be part of the class, so you can't use it in a template directly; you'd have to assign it to a property first:

```
export default class HelloWorld extends LightningElement {
  handleClick = handleClick;
}
```

---

Second, you can create a mixin class for common methods:

```
const Utils = (superclass) => class extends superclass {
  handleClick(event) {
    this.clickedButtonLabel = event.target.label;
  }
}
export { Utils }
```

Which you then use in the main component:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { Utils } from 'c/utils';

export default class HelloWorld extends Utils(LightningElement) {
  // .. rest of code
```

This has the advantage of placing the method directly into the controller, so it can be called directly from a template:

```
<div onclick={handleClick}>...</div>
```

Mixins allow you to combine multiple units at once, so it is more flexible than class inheritance.

---

The third option is to extend a `LightningElement`:

```
// utils
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
class CustomElement extends LightningElement {
  handleClick(event) {
    ...
  }
}
export { CustomElement }
```

Which you can then use as a replacement for LightningElement:

```
// helloWorld.js
import { CustomElement } from 'c/utils';
export default class HelloWorld extends CustomElement {
  ...
}
```

Like the second option, this automatically fixes "this". If you have a lot of components that have very similar structure, this can also be a useful technique.

---

Note that, in all of these examples, `test1` is fixed to the file in which is defined in. In other words, `HelloWorld` won't be able to access `test1` in any of the three scenarios. It is a part of `utils`, and so can't be directly accessed from outside the `utils.js` file (unless exported).

Answer (score 1):

Create LWC of name **utils**.
Use **utils.js** as below:

```js
export function externalFunction(event){
//function logic
//return data as per logic 
}
```

In **LWC** component **js** file import the function to use it:

```js
import { externalFunction } from "c/utils";

handleClick(event) {
    let returnvalue = externalFunction.bind(this)(event);
}
```

Comment: Close, but the asker specifically asked about `this`, which is undefined in an imported method. You can fix it by using `bind`.